# p5.js How to delete the last draw()

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm not quite sure how to word this. I've been messing around with p5, and always come across this "error".

```
function setup(){
    createCanvas(400,400);
}

function draw(){
    textSize(32);
    text(second(), 10, 30);
}
```

All I'm trying to do is display the second. However, what happens is that it displays the second e.g `50`, and then when `second == 51`, it simply writes over the `50`. What I would prefer to happy is for the browser to display 50, delete 50, display 51, delete 51... The image below represents what is being displayed.

[image: over-writing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `draw` function, just draw/redraw the background as well :

```
function draw () {
  background(90, 90, 90);
  textSize(32);
  text(second(), 10, 30);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Would I be create in assuming that the draw() function simply re-renders the entire canvas?

Comment: Usually yes a draw() function reset the entire canvas allowing to update all "moving" objects inside a single function. Then inside draw() you can call individually the functions that update your objects.